# How to display a list of files in a Cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, nsoutlineview

I am making an OSX Cocoa application in Xcode.  I want to have a panel on the left side of the app that displays a clickable list of the files in the given folder and when the user clicks on one that file should open in a NSTextView on the right side of the app.  I have figured out how to open, save and write to the files in the given folder, but I am at a loss for how to make a selectable view with file names.

I was thinking about using an OnClicked method for file opening.

Also, I do not want to use the OpenFile drop down panel, I want the files to be shown on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`NSOutlineView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display the list of files. You can populate it by iterating through the filesystem with [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Then, when the outline view's selection changes, you can read the contents of the file and set the `NSTextView`'s `string` property.